# Changing HTML Files

Tags: html

I had a bunch of HTML files in a folder. I opened them with Google Chrome to see how they looked. When I went back to the folder of all of the HTML files, they are all changed to Chrome HTML Document. How do I change them back to just regular HTML documents?

Comment: Right click -> open with -> choose default -> then select your favourite editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using windows you can go to the 'Default Programs' section of the control panel and choose 'Set Associations' to change the default application for .html files to be associated with your preferred program (notepad++, dreamweaver, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

They're still HTML files. What has changed is that Google Chrome has been set as the default application for opening files with the .html extension, and the description for those filetypes has been set as 'Chrome HTML document'.